# What does the word "pinche" mean?

Tags: definiciones, diferencias-regionales, modismos, méxico, significado

What does the word ***pinche*** mean?

> ¡Pinche loco!
>
> ¡Pinche!

---

¿Cuál es el significado de la palabra ***pinche***?

> ¡Pinche loco!
>
> ¡Pinche!

Comment: You are asking about Mexico, isn't it? In other places, a *pinche* is just a cook's aid.

Comment: In Spain pinche is just cook's aid, as @Gorpik said. I know there are other meanings in other countries.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm Mexican and we never use `pinche` as Kitchen boy, though some Mexicans would know it also means chef's helper. We always use it as an insult enhancer and can turn almost any curse word into a really rude one:

- pinche pendejo/pendeja = fucking asshole
- pinche puto/puta = fucking faggot/whore
- pinche culero = fucking asshole

When used alone as an adjective it just means something lousy, ugly, something that sucks.

> Esta fiesta esta bien pinche
>   <sub>This party is really lousy / This party really sucks</sub>

Answer (score 29):

1. **Kitchen boy**. The guys who clean up the Chef's mess and scrub the frying pans and carry stuff around. In this context it's still used in Spain.
2. **In Mexico**, it's an all-purpose insult enhancer, which would be roughly equivalent to the use of *fucking* in English. If Jay (Silent Bob's hetero life mate) spoke Spanish, he would say *pinche* A LOT. 
   Pinche is strongly associated with cursing in Mexican Spanish and the very moment you use it gives you away as a Mexican national. So you pinches gringos take that into account if youre trying to pass for an Argentine or whatever.
3. **In Mexico**, it's also used as an adjective to describe something as insignificant, lousy, miserable or worthless.

Examples:

> Pinche gringo culero ve a chingar a tu reputisima madre! (Fucking
>   gringo asshole go fuck your loosecunt cocksucking mother!)
>
> Tu pinche hermana está bien pinche, wey. (Your fucking sister is so
>   fucking ugly, dude!)

in the last example, the first *pinche* means only *fucking* while the second means **fucking ugly**

Comment: And hope I could give another +1 for the Jay & Bob reference :D

Comment: Well, I didn't understand the Jay & Bob reference. Anyway, sometimes *pinche* is a compliment. Like somebody makes a cruel joke and you laugh and say "¡qué pinche eres!", but I guess that is encompassed in your point 3, plus sarcasm.

Comment: So it has the same origin as the English word [slut](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=slut)... interesting.

Answer (score 6):

Añado esta referencia de acuerdo con lo indicado en [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483/1674). Edita libremente para incluir la versión de tu país o región.

---

#### Chile

- Hair clip

#### Colombia

- Derogatory term for things and people

#### Costa Rica

- Describes people as "cheap" and/or "ugly"

#### Guatemala

- Denotes a perceived lack of value about something. It is derogatory in nature and can be translated as miserable, trivial, wretched, insignificant, etc.

#### México

- Insult enhancer (equivalent to the use of *fucking* in English)
- Adjective to describe something as insignificant, lousy, miserable or worthless.

#### Nicaragua

- Describes people as "cheap" or "stingy"

#### Panamá

- Insult enhancer

#### Spain

- Kitchen boy

#### Cuba

- To work

Comment: In Colombia it's used a derogatory term, **pinche carro** means _this cars is a piece of junk_, also used with people, meaning useless, inferior, underperformer.

Comment: In Guatemala pinche is used to denote a perceived lack of value about something. It is part of the informal vocabulary and is not considered an insult although still derogatory in nature. Safe translations in Guatemala would be:
miserable, trivial, wretched, insignificant, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In Nicaragua it is used as a term to describe people as "cheap" or "stingy":

> Eres pinche

means

> You're cheap/stingy

In south Texas it's used the same way; also used to imply something as cheap or worthless.

> "Ese viejo es bien pinche" means "That man is really stingy"
>
> "Ese pinche viejo no hace nada bien!" means that worthless man doesn't do anything well.

Answer (score 2):

In Chile if you say "pinche" it most likely means hair clip. It's a hair clip.

Example:

> Pásame el pinche   <sub>Pass me the hair clip</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I am of Mexican descent and have friends from Panama and Colombia that both understand *pinche* as "fucking." It is not just isolated to Mexico.